# Magento Resources and API Data Sources

Tags: magento

As I work with third-party APIs pretty frequently, I thought it would be helpful to create some Magento modules to enable easy connection and querying of them.  Ideally, you could query an API like this...

```
$data = Mage::getModel( 'tools/apixyz_list' )->getCollection();
```

It would instantiate a model for one of the list items, then attempt to get a collection of them by querying the API.  This would require some kind of hookup in the config between the Resource Model and the API and that's where I'm having a little trouble.

Is there a recommended way to do this?  I'm having a lot of difficulty finding anything on the subject yet I feel like it should be a pretty common issue given the amount of APIs that generally need to get integrated from project to project.

Comment: Nope, no recommended way of doing this.  All the 3rd party API interrogations eschew the Magento model system and roll something on their own, and 1st party API integrations use a more specialized model format (payment, shipping, etc).  You initial feeling may be that "it should already exists because it's a common issue", but follow that to your second feeling, which is "someone should have already built this".  Everyone else feels the same way, and so it never gets built.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!  I actually built this for Recurly - I'm trying to get it open sourced, but it's not open yet.  Here's a snippet from the load() method which is the guts of it.

```
// TBT_Recurly_Model_Resource_Recurly_Abstract_Collection
public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    if ($this->isLoaded()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if ($this->_isCached()) {
        return $this->_loadCache();
    }

    $this->_beforeLoad();
    $this->_renderFilters()
        ->_renderOrders()
        ->_renderLimit();
    $this->clear();

    try {
        # This is ultimately doing the API call
        $recurly_list = $this->_getListSafe();
    } catch (Recurly_Error $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->setConnectionError($e->getMessage());
        return $this;
    }

    foreach ($recurly_list as $recurly_item)
    {
        $item = $this->getNewEmptyItem();
        $item->getResource()->setDataOnObject($item, $recurly_item);

        // Recurly appears to sometimes return duplicate subscription items in it's list response.
        if (!isset($this->_items[$item->getId()])) {
            $this->addItem($item);
        }
    }
    $this->_afterLoadRecurly();

    // We have to setIsLoaded before we saveCache b/c otherwise it will infinite loop
    $this->_setIsLoaded();
    $this->_saveCache();
    $this->_afterLoad();
    return $this;
}
```

We actually ended up taking this and putting it into a base REST class, and it was really cool because it ended up being really easy to implement new REST APIs on top of it.

As far as best practice goes, I'm not sure that I've answered your question specifically.  But basically I think the main things to do to  make it clean are:

- Follow the Magento models / collection method signatures for querying.
- Implement caching
- Implement the API communication in the resource model layer

Comment: I'm finding that the only way I can get this type of operation to work is to bypass the resource layer altogether.  Even at it's base, `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract` is still specialized for database usage and it attempts to connect to DB tables specified in the config.

Comment: Mage is definitely heavily geared towards DB, but I have to hand it to them they have the pieces in place needed to abstract beyond the DB.  I actually extended Varien_Data_Collection directly in my resource collection.  I did extend Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract in the resource model.